always import numpy at idlex startup in windows
I'm running idlex,1.2.2 on windows 10 using idlex.py. I would like to import numpy and others every time it starts.  Is there a way to do this?
I tried adding import numpy in idlex.py and it had on effect, same when I added it in idlexMain
